# MongoDB: elemMatch match the last element in an array

Tags: mongodb

I have the data like below:

```
{
"order_id" : 1234567,
"order_pay_time" : 1437373297,
"pay_info" : [
    {
        "pay_type" : 0,
        "pay_time" : 1437369046
    },
    {
        "pay_type" : 0,
        "pay_time" : 1437369123
    },
    {
        "pay_type" : 0,
        "pay_time" : 1437369348
    }
]}
```

what I want to get is the last payment is of type 1, but `$elemMatch` just match the list where pay_type:1 exists, how can I match the orders which last payment is of `"pay_type" : 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation) to get expected output. The query will be like following:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $unwind: "$pay_info"
}, {
    $match: {
    "pay_info.pay_type": 1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    "pay_info": {
        $push: "$pay_info"
    },
    "order_id": {
        $first: "$order_id"
    },
    "order_pay_time": {
        $first: "$order_pay_time"
    }
    }
})
```

Moreover if you want latest `pay_info.pay_time` then you can `sort` it by descending order with `limit` 1, some what like following:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $unwind: "$pay_info"
}, {
    $match: {
    "pay_info.pay_type": 1
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
    "pay_info.pay_time": -1
    }
}, {
    $limit: 1
}, {
    $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    "pay_info": {
        $push: "$pay_info"
    },
    "order_id": {
        $first: "$order_id"
    },
    "order_pay_time": {
        $first: "$order_pay_time"
    }
    }
})
```

**Edit**

Also you can use [$redact](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/implement-field-level-redaction/) to avoid $unwind like following:

```
db.collection.aggregate({

    $match: {
    "pay_info": {
        $elemMatch: {
            "pay_type": 1
        }
    }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
    "pay_info.pay_time": -1
    }
}, {
    $limit: 1
}, {
    $redact: {
    $cond: {
        if: {
            $eq: [{
                "$ifNull": ["$pay_type", 1]
            }, 1]
        },
        then: "$$DESCEND",
        else: "$$PRUNE"
    }
    }
}).pretty()
```

Comment: Want's to match *"the **last** 'pay_type' = 1"*, therefore meaning  ordered by date. Not what you are doing here.

Comment: thx, it did solve the problem, but the process deals with unwind and rewind  operation, Is there any solution without using this method?

Answer (score 2):

Just found this thread for a similar problem I've had.

I ended up doing this, maybe that will be of interest to someone:

```js
db.collection.find({
    $where: function(){
        return this.pay_info[this.pay_info.length-1].pay_type === 1
    }
})
```